# Can't jump while moving

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I've encountered a bug where I can run and walk but can't jump while doing so. If I'm not moving I can jump. I've ruled out encumbrance by trying this with empty bags. How can I fix this?

I'm playing Skyrim - Legendary Edition on Windows 7.

Comment: Using a controller or a keyboard? What are you run and jump mapped to?

Comment: space for jump and w for run/walk

Comment: Restart the game, restart computer, remap keys, try without mods, try on a new game. Was this happening from the start of your first play through or did it occur somewhere in the game? So many factors go with bugs you should clarify your bug much more. and what you tried already.

Answer (score 2):

You could try entering and exiting sneak mode and also check under the Magic-tab if your character has any illnesses. That's what these sources of people with similar problems suggest, but they complain about not being able to jump at all:

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120123232028AAe9sfB

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130806094434AAkBQ6e

Also, if you have one you could try loading an older save and see if it still works there.

(I would have commented this, but unfortunately I lack the reputation.)

Comment: this happens on multiple chars and sneaking doesn't seem to do anything to it though i can't enter sneak while I'm moving either

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a semi-common bug that happens from time to time. You're animation is stuck in sneak mode but the game doesn't realize it.

Use something that forcibly resets your animation/position should fix it (crafting stations, werewolf/dawnguard vampire transformations).

Answer (score 0):

This is the same on my keyboard and I heard that Logitech (for my point) blocket this by their driver, because they want to sell their expensive gaming keyboards. I could imagine, that other companies do the same. You cannot press Ctrl + W + Space at the same time (well you can, but it doesn't do what you want).

I hate stuff like this, because they did extra work to cut the opportunities you'd have. You can maybe change the keys for this actions, but I don't know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was my own keyboard. I swapped back to an older 1 and it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If other things don't work be certain Caps Lock is not set. It is equivalent to always holding shift which feels similar to being stuck in sneak.